# Delete row mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Using the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $first = get_post('first');
    $query = "DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id='$id'";
    if(!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

$query="SELECT * FROM user_master";
$result= mysql_query($query);

if(!result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j=0 ; $j<$rows ; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>
    ID      $row[0]
    First   $row[1]
    Last    $row[2]
    Email   $row[3]
    User    $row[4]
    </pre>
    <form action="willingLog.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[0]" />
    <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD" /></form>
_END;
```

I'm unable to delete a record form the table.

All the records form the table are printing on the screen, including the "DELETE RECORD" button.  When I hit the button, however, nothing happens.  I've checked the actual table on phpmyadmin, and the table is unaffected as well.

I'm pulling this stuff from a book, so I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: I'd suggest getting a better book. :)  From the looks of it the one you're using was published years ago.

Comment: There is no delete sql in this example

Comment: I don't see any code anywhere that comes even close to doing what you want. `$_POST`? `DELETE FROM`? Where are they?

Comment: What does your delete button do? Right now it seems the form sends the user to willingLog.html... In order to delete the actual row, this page would have to process the filled in form and run a mysql delete query.

Comment: I think I need another book, for sure.  Any thoughts?  Also, I added some more code on the top to show delete procedure.

Comment: Does the code ever get to the if block with the delete?  if it does does it show any error.  Does your get_post function exist?  what happens if you display php errors.  does anything show?

Comment: when I click on "delete record" nothing happens.  no errors.  nada.

Comment: What does this code do `$first = get_post('first');`? Is it setting a variable? Add some debugging and echo out your SQL statement to make sure it looks like what you think it looks like.

Comment: @dwstein  That tells me that the first thing i would check is if it makes it to the block...   second... does the get_post function work or is it broken?

Comment: code should read $id = get_post('id');

Comment: Does the delete work when you change that line?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see where you set the `$id` variable.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id']))
{
    //$first = get_post('first');   #not sure what this does
    $id = sanitize($_POST['id'], 'int');  //protect from sql injection
    $query = "DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id=$id";
    if(!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Please be sure to sanitize any data sent across the network, i.e. `$_POST`. Also, if `id` is of a number type, do not surround the value in quotes or mysql will interpret it as a string.

Lastly, look into using [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as MySql API has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here i defined a variable from that variable i delete the values

$id = 2;

```
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id="'.$id.'"");
```

note: Delete query id is important otherwise it delete whole rows defaulty.

Answer (score 1):

$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=1");

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id='$id'";
```

This should probably be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'] "'";
```

But please do some research into SQL injection, and why you should never pass information directly from the user into the database.

Comment: That's not a very good example if you are warning him about sql injection lol.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. I think it's an excellent example; just possibly not in the way he'd like.

Answer (score 0):

code should read:

```
$id = get_post('id');
```

in the first line of the curly braces under the first "if" statement.